# How do I read data in one cell and write data into another cell using Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets-api

So let's all assume that column B is filled with multiple, short statements. These statements may be used more than once, not at all, or just once throughout the column. I want to be able to read what's in each cell of column B and assign a category to it in column F using the Google Sheets script editor. I'll include some pseudo-code of how I would do something like this normally.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < statements.length; i++) {
  if (statements[i] == 'Description One') {
     category[i] = 'Category One';
  }
  else if (statements[i] == 'Description Two') {
     category[i] = 'Category Two';
  }
  // and so on for all known categories....
}
```

How do I go about accessing a cell for a read and accessing a different cell for a write?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after a little more thought on the subject, I've arrived at a solution. It's super simple, albeit tedious

```
function assignCategory(description) {
  if (description == 'Description One') {
    return 'Category One';
  }
  // and so on for all known categories
}
```

Hopefully someone will see this and be helped anyway, if you guys think of a more efficient and easier to maintain way of doing this, by all means do chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a sheet such as [this](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gX1iJ9V7MstoFHmJJbEnLjbP5uYiNUwdPe0i7ca-Dws/edit?usp=sharing) one, which has a header and six different columns (where B is the description, and F the category); you could use a dictionary to translate your values as follows:

```js
// (description -> category) dictionary
var translations = {
  "cooking": "Cooking",
  "sports": "Sport",
  "leisure": "Leisure",
  "music": "Music",
  "others": "Other"
}

function assignCategories() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  for (var i=2; i<=dataRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var description = dataRange.getCell(i, 2).getValue();
    var category = translations[description];
    dataRange.getCell(i, 6).setValue(category);
  }
}
```

In case you need additional ruling (i.e. descriptions that **contain** cricket must be classified as sport), you could accomplish your desired results by implementing your own custom function and using string functions (such as [indexOf](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp)) or [regular expressions](https://scriptingwithshiva.blogspot.com/2018/04/google-apps-script-regular-expressions.html).

#### Using indexOf

```js
// (description -> category) dictionary
var translations = {
  "cooking": "Cooking",
  "sports": "Sport",
  "leisure": "Leisure",
  "music": "Music",
  "others": "Other"
}

function assignCategories() {
  var dataRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange();
  for (var i=2; i<=dataRange.getNumRows(); i++) {
    var description = dataRange.getCell(i, 2).getValue()
    var category = assignCategory(description);
    if (category) dataRange.getCell(i, 6).setValue(category);
  }
}

function assignCategory(description) {
  description = description.toLowerCase();
  var keys = Object.keys(translations);
  for (var i=0; i<categories.length; i++) {
    var currentKey = keys[i];
    if (description.indexOf(currentKey) > -1)
      return translations[currentKey];
  }
}
```

This version is a bit more sophisticated. It will make the 'description' of each row lowercase in order to better compare with your dictionary, and also uses indexOf for checking whether the 'translation key' appears in the description, rather than checking for an exact match.

You should be aware however that this method will be considerably slower, and that the script may timeout (see [GAS Quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas)). You could implement ways to 'resume' your script operations such that you can re-run it and continue where it left off, in case that this hinders your operations.

Comment: Yes, I would likely have to implement a custom function using indexOf. I'm essentially reading bank statement descriptions and assigning a category for descriptions that appear regularly. However, your implementation appears to be much easier to maintain. I've toyed around with the idea of implementing a map of descriptions and categories. I've got ten months worth of descriptions all in a sheet with duplicates removed and categories assigned. So creating a map of that data wouldn't be too difficult.Essentially I want to assign all that I can on import and manually assign what it misses.

Comment: @freebird I have updated my answer using `indexOf()` and also lowercasing the description. Let me know if that suits your needs. Cheers